# UITableView with UIViewRepresentable in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, swiftui

I am trying to use `UITableView` in a SwiftUI app

```
struct UIList: UIViewRepresentable {

    var rows: [String]

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITableView {
        let collectionView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.dataSource = context.coordinator
        collectionView.delegate = context.coordinator
        collectionView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        return collectionView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITableView, context: Context) {
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(rows: rows)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

        var rows: [String]

        init(rows: [String]) {
            self.rows = rows
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            self.rows.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let tableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) //as! AlbumPrivateCell

            let view = Text(rows[indexPath.row]).frame(height: 50).background(Color.blue)// UIFactory(appComponent:

            let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: view)

            let tableCellViewContent = controller.view!

            tableCellViewContent.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            tableViewCell.contentView.addSubview(tableCellViewContent)

            tableCellViewContent.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableViewCell.contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
            tableCellViewContent.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableViewCell.contentView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
            tableCellViewContent.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableViewCell.contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            tableCellViewContent.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableViewCell.contentView.rightAnchor).isActive = true


            return tableViewCell
        }
    }
}
```

When I scroll the table quickly the cells content get a random padding at top and bottom of each cell, any idea why this happens ?

[image]
PS: I know I could use `List` , I try to use `UITableView` because I have to add multiple swipe actions, but `List` only allows one swipe action (delete)

Comment: The padding is consistent to the width of the string being displayed in the cell. Alternative solution could be to embed the SwiftUI view in a GeometryReader and then pass that geom to the UIList. Then, initialize your Coordinator with that value accordingly and set your cell frame width to geom.size.width.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I assume this is due to corrupted reused table view cells... (and probably lost hosting controllers, because there where created on stack and not stored anywhere)

Please find below corrected a bit your code with mentioned fixes. Tested & worked with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2.

Here is code (with some comments inline):

```
class HostingCell: UITableViewCell { // just to hold hosting controller
    var host: UIHostingController<AnyView>?
}

struct UIList: UIViewRepresentable {

    var rows: [String]

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITableView {
        let collectionView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.dataSource = context.coordinator
        collectionView.delegate = context.coordinator
        collectionView.register(HostingCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        return collectionView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITableView, context: Context) {
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(rows: rows)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

        var rows: [String]

        init(rows: [String]) {
            self.rows = rows
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            self.rows.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let tableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! HostingCell

            let view = Text(rows[indexPath.row])
                    .frame(height: 50).background(Color.blue)
            
            // create & setup hosting controller only once
            if tableViewCell.host == nil {
                let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: AnyView(view))
                tableViewCell.host = controller
                
                let tableCellViewContent = controller.view!
                tableCellViewContent.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                tableViewCell.contentView.addSubview(tableCellViewContent)
                tableCellViewContent.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableViewCell.contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
                tableCellViewContent.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableViewCell.contentView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
                tableCellViewContent.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableViewCell.contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
                tableCellViewContent.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableViewCell.contentView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
            } else {
                // reused cell, so just set other SwiftUI root view
                tableViewCell.host?.rootView = AnyView(view)
            }
            tableViewCell.setNeedsLayout()
            return tableViewCell
        }
    }
}
```

Added demo code for just `UIList` itself - works fine with pro models as well.

[image: demo]

```
struct TestUIList: View {
    var body: some View {
        UIList(rows: generateRows())
    }
    
    func generateRows() -> [String] {
        (0..<100).reduce([]) { $0 + ["Row \($1)"] }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've noticed that big views get clipped, e.g. if the Text is very long, it clips out. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @Asperi this solution really helped but the problem still occurs to the tablecell which are hidden. Their layout render badly. Can you solve this as well. Appeared TableCells are working perfectly