# Swiftui UIViewRepresentable table view having padding while scrolling

Tags: swiftui

Why having padding while scrolling the table view although added Hosting cell to hold the view and create the view once time only. Any idea regarding my mistake?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TUym.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60008452/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi...I referring this question but also having padding once scrolling....