# iOS: UI Distortion when using SwiftUI views in UIKit TableView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am attempting to reuse a SwiftUI view inside a UIKit tableView but noticed that the UI gets distorted after some interaction with the UI.

See the GIFs attached. Notice that the first 2 cells, ie Title 0 and Title 1, gets distorted after several swipes on the tableView.

[image]

Code:

```
class TestController: UITableViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        navigationItem.title = "Test"
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.register(TestCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TestCell
        cell.title = "Title \(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }
}

class TestCell: UITableViewCell  {
    
    var title: String? {
        didSet {
            if let title = title {
                let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: TestView(text: title))
                let hostingView = hostingController.view
                hostingView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                contentView.addSubview(hostingView ?? UIView())
                hostingView?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
                hostingView?.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
                hostingView?.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
                hostingView?.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

In the TestCell, I have also attempted using `addSubview(hostingView ?? UIView())` instead of `contentView.addSubview` but it yielded the same outcome.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60008452/12299030?

Comment: Thanks @Asperi. Yes that SO post answers my question.