# SwiftUI - Custom UITableView not loading, delegate methods are executing except cellForRow

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

I have situation where I have to use `UIKit` custom view with `TableView` inside `SwiftUI` but table view is not appearing in `SwiftUI`, however delegate methods are executing except for the `cellForRow`. I am not using storyboard in my project.

Example

**Here is my custom view with my tableview and delegate methods**

```
class CustomTableView: UIView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var tableView: MyCustomTableView {
        let tableview = MyCustomTableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
        tableview.delegate = self
        tableview.dataSource = self
        return tableview
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello \(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
   }
}
```

**This is my tableview**

```
class MyCustomTableView: UITableView {

    override init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableView.Style) {
        super.init(frame: frame, style: style)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

**This is my Representable for `CustomTableView`**

```
struct CustomTableViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> CustomTableView {
        CustomTableView(frame: .zero)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: CustomTableView, context: Context) {
        uiView.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

**This is my SwiftUI view which will load on one of the button click event**

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomTableViewRepresentable()
        }.background(Color.yellow)
    }
}
```

Please help and advise. Thanks.

I added code in details section that I tried but I have no luck. I am missing something but don't know what is it?

Here is the link to Sample project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q0nfphass8tohhb/TableViewPOC.zip?dl=0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60008452/14260241

Comment: I checked this example but I have different scenario. I am NOT making UITableView as UIViewRepresentable for SwiftUI. I have custom view and UITableView is inside custom view.

Comment: where are you adding `tableView` in View's hierarchy? you need to add in `CustomTableView`'s `init` method `addSubview(tableView)` with constraints. `CustomTableView` is subclass of `UIView` so `reloadData()` method directly not available. You need to handle it in `CustomTableView` class and then call it in `CustomTableViewRepresentable`

Comment: I tried @kishanBhatiya but it is still not woking. I updated the details and added sample project. https://www.dropbox.com/s/q0nfphass8tohhb/TableViewPOC.zip?dl=0

Comment: why don't you go for List ? Or Grids

Comment: The `tableView` property in `CustomTableView` creates a new table view each time it is accessed. It needs to be a lazy property.

Comment: as @GeoffHackworth said, currently `tableView` is computed property of `MyCustomTableView` which computes a value each time it is accessed. A new instance of `MyCustomTableView` is created every time `tableView` is accessed. Use private stored property with lazy initialization which create tableview once and  reuse across multiple calls.

Comment: `private let tableView: MyCustomTableView = {
        let tableView = MyCustomTableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
        return tableView
    }()` and setup constraints also and check it

Comment: Thank you all. I tried registering cell, make table view lazy and set the constraint and I can see table view populating data.

Answer (score 0):

You have neither set your `MyCustomTableView`'s frame nor set `Autolayout` constrains.

Please give enough layout data to it so that it can be successfully rendered.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to register a `Cell`, so you need to call `register(_:forReuseIdentifier:)`**, as follows:

```swift
var tableView: MyCustomTableView {
  let tableview = MyCustomTableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
  tableview.delegate = self
  tableview.dataSource = self
  tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self,
                     forCellReuseIdentifier: "DefaultCell")
  return tableview
}
```

So use one of the following:

1. Default: `tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DefaultCell")`
2. Custom: `tableView.register(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DefaultCell")`
3. From Nib: `tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "yourNib", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "DefaultCell")`

**And later in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`, you'll need to manipulate the registered cell by using `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)`**, like the following:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DefaultCell")
  else { return ... }

  // Cell customizations...

  return cell
}
```

Comment: @HVN You're welcome.
Please accept this answer if it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution.